# Blending issue porting from OpenGLES 1.0 to 2.0 (iOS)

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, alphablending, opengl-es-1.1

I'm porting a very simple piece of code from OpenGLES 1.0 to OpenGLES 2.0.

In the original version, I have blending enabled with

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendEquation(GL_FUNC_ADD);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

I'm using the same code in my ES 2.0 implementation as I need to blend the newly rendered quads with what was in the render buffer (I'm retaining the render buffer, I can't re-render the scene).

I'm using a texture (alpha values displaying a radial gradient from center to the outside, alpha goes from 1 to 0) that serves as an alpha mask, containing only white pixels with different alpha values. I give my vertices the same color say red with alpha of 100/255. My background is transparent black. Below that, I have a plain white surface (UIView). I render 4 quads.

Result with OpenGLES 1.0 (desired result)
[image]

My observations tells me that the fragment shader should simply be:

```
gl_FragColor = DestinationColor * texture2D(Texture, TexCoordOut);
```

(I got to that conclusion by trying different values for my vertices and the texture. That's also what I've read on some tutorials.)

I'm trying to write some OpenGL 2.0 code (including vertex + fragment shaders) that would give me the exact same result as in OpenGLES 1.0, nothing more, nothing less. I don't need/want to do any kind of blending in the fragment shader except applying the vertex color on the texture. Using the simple shader, here's the result I got:
[image]

I tried pretty much every combination of *, +, mix I could think of but I couldn't reproduce the same result. This is the closest I got so far, but that's definitely not the right one (and that doesn't make any sense either)

```
varying lowp vec4 DestinationColor;
varying lowp vec2 TexCoordOut;
uniform sampler2D Texture;

void main(void) {
    lowp vec4 texture0Color = texture2D(Texture, TexCoordOut);
    gl_FragColor.rgb = mix(texture0Color.rgb, DestinationColor.rgb, texture0Color.a);
    gl_FragColor.a = texture0Color.a * DestinationColor.a;
}
```

This shader gives me the following:
[image]

Comment: Sorry, but your question is a bit unclear to me. What exactly is the result you need? Do you use blending in ES 2.0 too?

Comment: I apologize if it's not clear. Yes, I enabled blending in ES 2.0 the same way. I essentially need the same result as I've got in ES 1.0 but can't clearly describe it. I tried to describe how I set things up in ES 1.0 though. It's probably not sufficient...

Comment: I think the question should be a lot clearer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake. I only needed to normalize the vertex color in the vertex shader as I'm passing unsigned bytes in.

Comment: As a hint, you don't need to normalize those yourself. That's exactly what the `normalize` argument of `glVertexAttribPointer` (that you probably have always set to `GL_FALSE`) is for.

Comment: Need to wait 48hours... but will do

Answer (score 0):

By reading [this](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Blending) and [this](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glBlendFuncSeparate), one can construct the blending function.

Since you're using `glBlendFunc` and not `glBlendFuncSeparate`, all the 4 channels are being blended. Using the `GL_FUNC_ADD` parameter sets the output O to `O = sS + dD`, where `s` and `d` are the blending parameters, and `S` and `D` are the source and destination colors.

The `s` and `d` parameters are set by the `glBlendFunc`. `GL_ONE` sets `s` to `(1, 1, 1, 1)`, and `GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA` sets `d` to `(1-As, 1-As, 1-As, 1-As)`, where `As` is the alpha value of the source. Therefore, your blend is doing this (in vector form):

`O = S + (1-As) * D` which in `GLSL` is `O = mix(D, S, As)`, or:
`gl_FragColor = mix(DestinationColor, TexCoordOut, As)`.

If the result doesn't look similar, then please verify that you're not using `glBlend` or any other OpenGL APIs that may change the appearance of your final result. If that doesn't help, please post a screenshot of the different outputs.

Comment: I think I'd need to keep blending on as Vasaka pointed out (unless I render to texture and read the existing frame buffer in the shader). I think all I need is a way to apply the vertex color to my texture as it is done in ES 1.0

Answer (score 0):

this can't be done easily with shaders since blending have to read current framebuffer state.
You can achieve this with rendering to texture and passing it to shader, if you can get color would be in framebuffer then you are ok.

your equation is:

```
gl_FragColor = wouldBeFramebufferColor + (1-wouldBeFramebufferColor.a) * texture0Color;
```

but why do you want to do it in shaders AFAIK blending was not removed in OpenGL ES 2.0

Comment: I don't want to do the blending in shaders at all. I just need to port my code to OpenGL 2.0 in order to try the instanced drawing that has recently been added in iOS. I'm just trying to replicate the exact same thing I had with my OpenGL 1.0 code.

Comment: Just posted pictures, maybe that'll help

Comment: I agree regarding using `glBlend`. However, since iOS 6 this can be done using shaders, by using the [GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/EXT/EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch.txt) extension.